# strong capacitive coupling of mains to isolated output of AC/DC converter?

Tags: emc, isolation, ac-dc

I am using a RS-15-5 PSU from Meanwell for a test: [datasheet here](https://www.meanwell.com/productPdf.aspx?i=1#1)

I built the following circuit:
[image]

The left side (V1) is the mains side. The right side (V2, C3, L1, C2, R2) is the isolated DC side.

As a first test, I connected only R1 (and not C1) between earth and the isolated output. And I believed that this would pull the 0V node to Earth potential

To my surprise when checking the output voltage with an oscilloscope I got about 100V AC at 50 Hz on the 0V node. After checking with Spice, this leads me to believe that there is about 10 nF in C4 which is a parasitic capacitor.

When I added C1 to the circuit, the voltage of 0V with respect to earth was reduced to a couple of V at 50 Hz. See the scope shot taken of the 0V node, referencing earth.

[image]

Still this is a tremendous common mode voltage and spice tells me that there is mA's of 50 Hz common mode current through C1 and C4. When I short out C1 and R1 with an Amperemeter, the 0V voltage collapses as expected and I read 3 mA AC of current.

How then are isolated power supplies used without failing all EMI tests ? The output nodes will unavoidably have a large potential to all earthed conductors, e.g. the Chassis ?

Replacing R1/C1 with a short would get rid of the large common mode voltage but the output would not be isolated anymore.

Where is my problem in understanding ?

**EDIT:**

I checked two other wall plug AC/DC converters, a 3 prong one and a 2 prong one. Both showed similarly large AC common mode voltages with respect to Earth on their isolated DC sides. So I would exclude a fault in the Meanwell PSUs.

My conclusion at this point would be that all equipment running off isolated AC/DC converters would be floating around at large 50 Hz common mode voltages, unless its DC side is bonded via a very low resistance to Earth. Is this indeed the case ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122471/discussion-on-question-by-tobalt-strong-capacitive-coupling-of-mains-to-isolated).

Comment: `V2` is a voltage source and, without any `Rser` specified, it has zero internal resistance. If you intended to model it as a power supply, at the very least you need `Rser` (or some series resistance). Otherwise, `V2` acts as a short circuit.

Comment: Rser doesn't change anything. Even 1kOhm is still "a short" compared to the impedance of C4. And it makes sense because we are discussing CM noise which is anyway equal on the 15V and 0V nodes. And as I said, i mainly used spice to draw the circuit for stackexchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out now that this is indeed normal, unless a PSU with low leakage current rating (e.g. medical AC-DC converter) is used. There are Y caps between primary and secondary side of the isolation transformer commonly used to return RF CM switch noise. These caps have the side effect of leaking AC mains to the secondary side.

Here is one slightly longer explanation https://e2e.ti.com/support/power-management/f/power-management-forum/529895/y-capacitors-across-isolation-boundary-in-ac-dc-converters but others can be found in stack exchange when searching for the right terms (which I didn't know when creating this question).

There are a couple of options :

1. just connect secondary to earth if this is an option
2. use a medical grade converter hoping that its leakage is low enough for the intended application
3. Use a regular (non-medical grade) AC-DC converter, connect the output to earth and follow it up with a regular (non-medical grade) isolated DC-DC converter. Especially when several isolated voltage rails are necessary, this could be cheaper then getting many medical grade AC-DC converters.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have resolved the enigma about the SPICE model and reality

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsgbzv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

C4 and C5 are leakage (virtual) capacitors while the rest is real circuit.

You could be accidentally making ground loop if you connected a scope, which has already grounded shield and PE conductor on C1,R1.

Comment: Are the caps C4 and C5 included within the PSU ? It is a RS-15-5 btw, not an IRM-15-5

Comment: Actually. Yes I think a ground loop could be the simple reason.. The AC wire is a few meters long. Let me try to remove the large loop.. Edit: nope moving or tightening up the wire doesnt change the CM voltage in DC

Comment: So obviously, caps C4 and C5 will couple mains AC to the DC side. Are these unavoidable? Where does this capacitance come from ?

Comment: I will continue my answer at latter time.